# How to sort the query using concat?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to sort my query based on date like 2018-01, 2018-02, ....
But I am not getting correct result

This is what I have tried.

```
select 

concat(YEAR(trn.date), '-', MONTH(trn.date)) as date_result


FROM ....

ORDER BY date_result
```

### Result:

```
date_result
2018-1
2018-10
2018-11
2018-12
2018-2
```

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: I need 2018-1, 2018-2, 2018-3....

Answer (score 2):

You have to mention sort order like "asc" or "desc".
So the query should be like :
select

concat(YEAR(trn.date), '-', MONTH(trn.date)) as date_result

FROM ....

ORDER BY date_result desc

Answer (score 2):

```
select 
concat(YEAR(trn.date), '-', MONTH(trn.date)) as date_result
FROM yourtablename
ORDER BY YEAR(trn.date),MONTH(trn.date) order  by date_result desc
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `YEAR(trn.date),MONTH(trn.date)` in order by clause

```
select 
concat(YEAR(trn.date), '-', MONTH(trn.date)) as date_result
FROM yourtablename
ORDER BY YEAR(trn.date),MONTH(trn.date)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to sort your result, not to change it from `2018-1` to `2018-01` then one query you could use is:

```
SELECT 
    concat(YEAR(trn.DATE), '-', MONTH(trn.DATE)) AS date_result
FROM ....
ORDER BY trn.DATE;
```

If you want to change your result like `2018-01` then use this query:

```
SELECT 
    DATE_FORMAT(trn.DATE, '%Y-%m') AS date_result
FROM ....
ORDER BY trn.DATE;
```

Comment: is it possible to change to 01 ?

Comment: i added a answer, with the leading zeros

Answer (score 1):

The function `MONTH` returns an integer value. Therefore you are loosing leading zeros.
You could either cast to a varchar and adding a leading zero, or just selecting the month using `SUBSTRING`.

Solution with casting:

```
SELECT concat(YEAR(trn.DATE), '-', RIGHT('0' + CAST(MONTH(trn.date) AS varchar(2)),2) ) as date_result
FROM ....
ORDER BY trn.DATE;
```

Solution with substring:

```
SELECT concat(YEAR(trn.DATE), '-', SUBSTRING(trn.date,6,2)) as date_result
FROM ....
ORDER BY trn.DATE;
```